# setting stream data from express to angular controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am fetching twitter data stream with node.js using express.

For now I am using socket.io to emit the data event on a particular socket.And my angular controller is listening to this socket.

sample code snippet for node.js:

```
twit.stream('user', function(stream) 
{
   stream.on('data', function (data) {
  //console.log(data);
  io.sockets.emit('newTweet', data);
  });

});
```

Code snippet for angular controller :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
window.socket = socket;
socket.on('newTwitt', function (item) {
  //console.log("item: "+ item)
  //data processing here
}
```

Is there any better way to set the chunk data from stream to angular controller?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream you can try npm

Comment: a readable stream can be piped to writable stream. e.g. stream.pipe(response). [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) implements writable stream. Does socket.io socket implement writable stream?

Comment: [socket.io 1.0](http://socket.io) home page displays a tweet stream example.